# Get selected item in QListView

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to get the selected item when its pushed a button. I want to disable the button until the item be selected. I don't know if the methods that I need are in model class, QListView class, or if I should use a combination of methods of both classes

This it's my code:

QListView.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_QListView(object):
    def setupUi(self, QListView):
        QListView.setObjectName("QListView")
        QListView.resize(357, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(QListView)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(45, 34, 256, 192))
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(141, 238, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        QListView.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(QListView)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 357, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        QListView.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(QListView)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        QListView.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(QListView)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(QListView)

    def retranslateUi(self, QListView):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        QListView.setWindowTitle(_translate("QListView", "List View"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("QListView", "Selected"))
```

mainQListView.py

```
from QListView import Ui_QListView
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 

class ListView(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        for i in range(10):
            model.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(str(i)))
        self.listView.setModel(model)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getSelectedItem)

    def getSelectedItem(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = ListView()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the selectedIndexes method to get the QModelIndex of the selected items and use itemFromIndex to get the QStandardItem:

```py
class ListView(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        for i in range(10):
            model.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(str(i)))
        self.listView.setModel(model)

        self.listView.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(
            self.handle_selection_changed
        )
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)

    def handle_selection_changed(self):
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(bool(self.listView.selectedIndexes()))

    def handle_clicked(self):
        for index in self.listView.selectedIndexes():
            item = self.listView.model().itemFromIndex(index)
            print(item.text())
```

**Note:** It is not recommended that the names of new classes, variables or new files coincide with names of existing elements since it can generate silent errors (which are the most complicated to debug) so I recommend you change name of the QListView.py file.